# Obtener ruta de un archivo android studio

Tags: java, android

Buenas gente me podrían ayudar con esto, intento mandar un archivo txt a través por un mensaje de WhatsApp mediante código sin embargo cuando trato de obtener la ruta del archivo me me tira este error

`android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/com.example.plantas/files/registros.txt exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()`

la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo dentro del teléfono es
`/data/data/com.example.plantas/files/registros.txt`

cuando trato de obtener la ruta me da  `file:///data/user/0/com.example.plantas/files/registros.txt`, les dejo la el código de la función que utilizo

```
public void Enviar(View view) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"registros.txt");//Uso la memoria interna dentro de la carpeta files
        FileWriter archivo = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try{
            archivo= new FileWriter(file);
            pw = new PrintWriter((archivo));
            pw.println("texto");
            pw.flush();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);//Aqui guardo la ruta del archivo

        Intent share = new Intent();
        share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        try {
            startActivity(share);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Snackbar.make(view, "El dispositivo no tiene instalado WhatsApp", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lo suyo seria usar FileProvider, pero antes de hacer eso, prueba a modificar Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); por Uri  uri = Uri.parse(file.getPath()); En caso de funcionar, deberias agregar un if para comprobar la version del sdk. Házmelo saber y agregare una respuesta en su caso.

Comment: @Israel muchas gracias no me funciono me sale la misma ruta pero se añade un mensaje que dice no se acepta el tipo de archivo voy a intentar usar el FileProvider si tienes algún ejemplo te estaría agradecido si lo pudieses compartir también intente crear un directorio en la memoria interna pero no crea los directorios ya puse los permisos en el manisfest pero no entiendo porque

Comment: Intenta guardar la ruta en una variable String file.getAbsolutePath(); 
Después puedes convertir el string a uri si lo necesitas